# SQL Oracle How to convert String Week into date

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date

I have dates stored like String in database.
The format is 'yyyy-ww' (example: '2015-43').

I need to get the first day of the week.

I tried to convert this string into date but there is no 'ww' option for the function "to_date".

Do you have an idea to perform this convertion?

**EDIT**

Test results based on the answers -

Thanks for your anwsers, but I have many problems to apply your solutions to my context:

```
select
TRUNC ( 2015 + ((43 - 1) * 7), 'IW' )
from dual
```

==> Error : ORA-01722: invalid number

```
select
TRUNC(to_date('2015','YYYY')+ to_number('01') *7, 'IW')
from dual
```

==> 2015-02-02 00:00:00
I waited for a date in january

```
select
trunc(to_date(regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+',1,2), 'YYYY') + regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+') * 7, 'IW') dt2
from dual
```

==> 0039-09-14 00:00:00

```
select
regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+',1,2) as res1,
regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+') * 7 as res2
from dual
```

==> res1 = 01
==> res2 = 14105

Comment: add yours code please

Comment: I realize you may no longer be able to change things, however, for future reference (ie other readers, or for yourself the next time you build a table), never never never store dates in a text. sore dates as dates. always. You'll never regret it if you do, you'll always regret it if you don't (just as you're finding with this question .. much more complex then it should if it was stored as date in the first place ;) )

Answer (score 0):

try to use by truncate

```
with t as (
 select '16-2010' dt from dual
)
--
--
  select dt, 
         trunc(to_date(regexp_substr(dt, '\d+',1,2), 'YYYY') + regexp_substr(dt, '\d+') * 7, 'IW') dt2
 from t
```

Comment: Thank you too for your help. I tried to run the following queries without success:

select
trunc(to_date(regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+',1,2), 'YYYY') + regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+') * 7, 'IW') dt2
from dual

==> 0039-09-14 00:00:00


select
regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+',1,2) as res1,
regexp_substr('2015-01', '\d+') * 7 as res2
from dual

==> res1 = 01
==> res2 = 14105

Answer (score 0):

> I have dates stored like String in database.

You should never do that. It is a bad design. you should store date as **DATE** and not as a **string**. For all kinds of requirements for date manipulations Oracle provides the required **DATE functions and format models**. As and when needed, you could **extract/display** the way you want.

> I need to get the first day of the week.

`TRUNC (dt, 'IW')` returns the Monday on or before the given date.

Anyway, in your case, you have the literal as `YYYY-WW` format. You could first extract the year and week number and combine them together to get the date using **TRUNC**.

```
TRUNC ( year + ((week_number - 1) * 7)
      , 'IW
      )
```

So, the above should give you the Monday of the week number passed for that year.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT '2015-43' str FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT TRUNC(to_date(SUBSTR(str, 1, 4),'YYYY')+ to_number(SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '-',1)+1))*7, 'IW')
  5  FROM DATA
  6  /

TRUNC(TO_
---------
23-NOV-15

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to run the following queries without success:

select
TRUNC ( 2015 + ((43 - 1) * 7), 'IW' )
from dual

==> Error : ORA-01722: invalid number


select
TRUNC(to_date('2015','YYYY')+ to_number('01') *7, 'IW')
from dual

==> 2015-02-02 00:00:00

Comment: `select TRUNC(to_date('2015','YYYY')+ to_number('01') *7, 'IW') from dual;`

Comment: This query returns "2015-02-02 00:00:00" :(

Comment: Just think once. You need just the date portion.

Comment: The problem is not the format of the date but the first week of 2015 can't return a date in february! Why I have 02-02 for the week 01?

Comment: Because, if you read my answer, I said that `IW` will return you the `MONDAY` of the week number. And the monday for the 1st week, is 2nd Feb. What's the problem? If you want some other date, you just need to tweak the same query I gave above.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. I think I understood what you answered but for me the monday of the first week of 2015 is the 5th of january not the 2nd of february. I would like to obtain "2015-01-05 00:00:00" instead of "2015-02-02 00:00:00".

Comment: Don't be sorry. You need to explain your rules about the start of the week.

Comment: Ok. I think I can work with this query, I just need it for the year 2015. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As much as I agree, that **dates** should never be stored as strings, NoviceOracle is *not* storing a "date".

Comment: @Lalit: Not sure your query works properly.  Your first portion: `to_date(str,'yyyy')`  doesn't return Jan 1, 2015 .. which I believe you are trying to use as the base to add the weeks to?  For me, it's adding Feb 1 O.o  it should probably be:  `to_date(str||'0101','yyyymmdd')`  to guarantee what date you're getting back.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, it's a date ... it's masked a bit, but it's still a date.  If you trunc off the TIME portion .. it's still a date. If you trunc off the day ... it's still a date. It's a less specific date, but it's still a date. When you strip everything off and end up with only the year, you sort of have an argument for it being a number at that point ;) but what he's got is just an inaccurate date.  Making it very hard to work with. If he had stored: `trunc(<date>,'W')` it would have been easier to work with, and still had the same information ;)

Comment: Typo in my above comment, should be: `trunc(<date>,'WW')` (ie WW, not W)  (actually, that's not even accurate, forgot 'IW' is ISO standard, 'WW" isn't ... *sigh* ) :)

Answer (score 0):

According ISO the 4th of January is always in week 1, so your query should look like

```
Select 
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_column, '^\d{4}')||'-01-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    + 7*(REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_column, '\d$')-1), 'IW') 
from your_table;
```

However, there is a problem. ISO year used for Week number can be different than actual year. For example, 1st Jan 2008 was in ISO week number 53 of 2007.

I think a proper working solution you get only when you generate ISO weeks from date value.

```
WITH w AS 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2010-01-04' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'IYYY-IW') AS week_number, 
        TRUNC(DATE '2010-01-04' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'IW') AS first_day
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY DATE '2010-01-04' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '7' DAY < SYSDATE)
SELECT your_Column, first_day
FROM w your_table
    JOIN w ON week_number = your_Column;
```

Your date range must bigger than `2010-01-04` and not bigger than current day.

Comment: No, that won't work. `IW` is not allowed for `to_date()`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Lalit's, however, I think I've corrected the math (his seemed to be off a bit when I tested .. )

```
  with w_data as (
     select sysdate + level +200  d  from dual connect by level <= 10
     ),
     w_weeks as (
        select d, to_char(d,'yyyy-iw') c
          from w_data
     )
  SELECT d, c, trunc(d,'iw'),
         TRUNC(
         to_date(SUBSTR(c, 1, 4)||'0101','yyyymmdd')-8+to_char(to_date(SUBSTR(c, 1, 4)||'0101','yyyymmdd'),'d')
         +to_number(SUBSTR(c, instr(c, '-',1)+1)-1)*7 ,'IW')
    FROM w_weeks;
```

The extra columns help show the dates before, and after.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT '2015-43' AS mydate FROM dual
)
SELECT TRUNC(TRUNC(TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(mydate, '^\d{4}'), 'YYYY'), 'YEAR') + (COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(mydate, '\d+$')), 0)-1) * 7, 'IW')
  FROM d1
```

The first thing the above query does is get the first four digits of the string `2015-43` and truncates that to the closest year (if you convert convert `2015` using `TO_DATE()` it returns a date within the current month; that is `SELECT TO_DATE('2015', 'YYYY') FROM dual` returns `01-FEB-2015`; we need to truncate this value to the `YEAR` in order to get `01-JAN-2015`). I then add the number of weeks *minus one* times seven and truncate the whole thing by `IW`. This returns a date of `01-OCT-2015` ([see SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40538)).

Comment: The outer `TRUNC` is of no use. Just one is enough.

Comment: The outer `TRUNC ()` is to get the first day of the week, otherwise it will return whatever day corresponds to 1 January (which in 2015 was Thursday).

Answer (score -1):

This is what I used:

```
select
to_date(substr('2017/01',1,4)||'/'||to_char(to_number(substr('2017/01',6,2)*7)-5),'yyyy/ddd') from dual;
```